# ESLint wrapper library could not be applied properly

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I created a wrapper ESLint library with the all required rules, plugins and options, and publishing it as an NPM library. I would like to simply use it in my other projects as a development dependency for linting (one for NodeJS projects, one for ReactJS projects).

- Created a project with two packages (`eslint-config-nodejs` and `eslint-config-react`)
- Includes only the following files: `.eslintrc.js`, `index.js`, `package.json`
- The index file has all the options exported, that is relevant for ESLint
- Package file lists all peer dependencies which should be installed with this dependency

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```js
{
  "name": "@xyz/eslint-config-nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "..."
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-regexp": "^1.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonar": "^0.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-wrapper": "0.0.3",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

**.ESLINTRC.JS**

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: require.resolve('./index'),
};
```

I also add the following script to my other project, before installing the ESLINT library:
`"postinstall": "npx install-peerdeps @xyz/eslint-config-nodejs --dev --pnpm",`

And I change the `.eslintrc` content in my project to:

```
{
  "extends": ["@xyz/eslint-config-nodejs"]
}
```

When doing the `pnpm install` everything seems to be fine, the peer dependencies are installed correctly, together with my ESLINT config library, but when I run the lint script, it seems that the linting rules are not applied correctly:

`1:1  error  Definition for rule 'sonar/no-nested-template-literals' was not found  sonar/no-nested-template-literals`
(and plenty other errors)

But the strange thing is when I execute the following command: `npx eslint --print-config "**/*.{js,ts}" | grep -A 2 sonar/no-nested-template-literals`

The result is:

```
    "sonar/no-nested-template-literals": [
      "error"
    ],
```

**INDEX.JS** (in the library)

```js
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
    'airbnb-typescript/base',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:sonar/recommended',
    'plugin:sonarjs/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  plugins: ['prettier', 'regexp', 'sonar', 'sonarjs'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  rules: {
    ...
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json'],
      },
    },
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    ...
  ],
};
```

This means to me that the configuration is injected but the linting is broken.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: It looks like, with version `"eslint-plugin-sonar": "0.12.0"` the rule `sonar/no-nested-template-literals` behaves strange. When I remove it from the config, linting passes.